# Is MAPI supported with Outlook 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, outlook, outlook-2007, outlook-2010

I am trying to use MAPI to display a public calendar in SharePoint. The below sample code works perfectly with a machine having Outlook 2007 installed. But Outlook 2010 does not displays a big white block.

Is this security? Is MAPI supported in Outlook 2010? Any advise is greatly appreciated.

```
<OBJECT classid=CLSID:0006F063-0000-0000-C000-000000000046
id=ViewCtlFolder
width="100%"
height="430"
codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/office/outlctl x.CAB#ver=9,0,0,3203">
<param name="Namespace" value="MAPI">
<param name="Folder" value="\\Public Folders\All Public Folders\Training Calendar">
<param name="Restriction" value="">
<param name="DeferUpdate" value="0">
</OBJECT>
```

Answer (score 1):

Outlook 2010 supports MAPI just fine. ***Unfortunately, you are not using MAPI***. You are using the [Outlook View Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869622.aspx).

Support for this control is still [included in Outlook 2010](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2511230), but it's use is restricted to in-process Outlook use, like custom folder pages.

Quote from the first link:

> Do not use the View Control in any scenario outside the Outlook process, such as in an HTML page hosted in a browser. Out-of-process scenarios are not supported.